# SimpleMDE: how to remove the autosave value

Tags: javascript, simplemde

I'm using [SimpleMDE](https://simplemde.com/) to add to my page a Markdown Editor. In the settings, there is an option for the `autosave`. When the user types something in the editor, periodically the script saves the changes in the *Local storare* of the browser. The name of the key can change but the key starts always with `smde_`

[image]

If I want to remove this key from the *Local Storage* I don't know how to do it. Is there a function in the SimpleMDE to remove this key?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clearAutosavedValue` method:

```js
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE();

simplemde.clearAutosavedValue();
```